# sqlplus is not working, it is frozen

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, sqlplus

When I type

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

It simply gets frozen, the cursor stays there, and I can type more character but after pressing enter nothing happens. Neither CTRL + C. My pmon service is running, ORACLE_HOME is established and ORACLE_SID is also there.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a full disk partition? All SYS actions are written to an OS audit trail file or files. It might hang like this if the audit trail can't be written to.

Comment: the inodes are ok, the disk is not full also.

Comment: Is there anything in the audit trail or the alert log indicating a problem? Any appearance of resource contention in the OS?

Comment: Try with strace: "strace sqlplus / as sysdba" . strace will reveal all system cals.